# How to make a scatter plot from data that made from groupby?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that contains data on covid19 sickness. I want to check the correlation at specific date, between the number of deaths cases to hospital bed.
I stuck at how to show the correlation, because I want to group it by country location the normal function of showing a scatter plot doesn't work...
that's what I did:

```
def corr_bedde(df):
    newdf=df[df.date == '2020-12-15']
    newdf = newdf.groupby('location')
    pltscatter = plt.scatter(newdf['total_cases_per_million'],newdf['hospital_beds_per_thousand'])
    corr = newdf['total_cases_per_million'].corr(newdf['hospital_beds_per_thousand'])
    return pltscatter ,corr
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be just the agg function after your groupby

```
def corr_bedde(df):
 newdf=df[df.date == '2020-12-15']
 newdf = newdf.groupby('location').sum()
 pltscatter= plt.scatter(newdf['total_cases_per_million'],newdf['hospital_beds_per_thousand'])
 corr= newdf['total_cases_per_million'].corr(newdf['hospital_beds_per_thousand'])
 return pltscatter ,corr
```